# How do I set TD width automatically all equal width

Tags: css

How do I set TDs width automatically all equal width ? without set the class name.
The TD can be 3 or 4 or whatever

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please help.

Comment: The code you have posted should work: http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/v0gm3fjw/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following example. It uses some JS to automate the process. It also uses CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) to let CSS do the math.

```js
const tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

for( let table of tables )
{
  let row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
  let columns = row.getElementsByTagName('td').length;
  
  table.style.setProperty('--columns', columns);
}
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  width: calc(100% / var(--columns));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps flexbox is a way to go.

This is a great reference that I use often:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
table{ width: 100%;   border: 1px solid #00aa00; }
  
table tr { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
td { 
  fleX: 0 1 auto; 
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think my solution deserves a down vote, but whatever.